# Dividing a tracking list items into two different edit forms, that have different permissions on each form

Tags: 2013, development, document-library, permissions, issue-tracking

I am trying to achieve the following, using the Issue Tracking list inside sharePoint server 2013. First I have an issue item which have the following columns:-

1. ID.
2. Title.
3. Date Created.
4. Description.
5. Assigned To Manager.
6. Type.
7. Manager Decision.
8. Manager cost (budget).

All users can create a new issue and enter the basic info such as;

1. ID.
2. Title.
3. Date Created.
4. Description.
5. Assigned To Manager.

Then the “Assigned to Manager” will receive an email, open the item, and fill the other fields:-

1. Type.
2. Manager Decision.
3. Manager cost (budget).

So my questions are:-

1. How I can implement this by dividing the issue item fields into two different Edit forms?
2. How I can divide the user’s permissions (user and manager) and specify who can add/edit the item data. so only managers can fill the following data; type, manager decision & Manager cost (budget)?

Regards

**EDIT**

I wrote the following inside VS :-

[image]

but i got error on `site.Group` and other commands , as shown in the above picture.so i think i am missing how i should write the web part ? can you advice what is wrong please?

**Edit Two**

currently i got the following inside the web part:-

[image]

so i am not sure where to add the asp control ?

Comment: how do you want to achieve this, custom web part would work?

Comment: @HardikKothari can you advice more on using web part in this situation ? i did not work on such a requirement before. but how i think it might work (not sure if this is available within SharePoint ) ; is to have two Forms instead of the default form which contains all the columns , and to define a workflow of two steps, and link each step within the workflow to a form !! can you advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with a approach using custom visual web part where you can show/hide and enable/disable the controls depending on the user permissions (Users,Managers Group) and attach a workflow or c# code for sending the email notification to Manager maintaining a flag on the list item action.

1) Create a custom web part.

2) Add the web part on your edit form using the below option
[image]

3) Code for your web part:

On PageLoad check for the user group and accordingly display/hide, enable disable the custom controls

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {SPGroup group = web.Groups["Managers"];
                    bool isUser = web.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(group.ID);
                    if (isUser)
                    {textbox.Visible=false;}}
```

And on custom buttons Save below code:

ASP Control:

```
<asp:Button id="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click"/>
```

CS Code:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        try
        {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
                   SPList list = web.Lists["ListName"];
                   web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                   SPListItem item = list.Items[SPContext.Current.ListItem.UniqueId];
                   txtTitle.Text = item["Title"] as string;
                   item.Update();
                   web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){}}
```

This would solve the purpose using single default Edit Form with a custom web part.

Edit : ASCX Control reference
[image]

Comment: Can you advice more on your approach ? and how web parts will help in my situation ?

Comment: kindly refer the edited answer.

Comment: so i need to write {textbox.Visible=false;} for all the columns that can be edited using the Managers only ? so in this way all the Manager-only fields must be read-only by default?

Comment: yes you can use it that way. for read only you can mention textbox.Enabled=false, this way you can control over users and operations on default form with custom visual web part

Comment: but when i want to add a new web part to the default edit form, what type of web part i need to add ? and do i have to develop it using visual studio ? i usually wirte web parts inside VS and publish them , and they will appear under the Custom list , so do i have to follow the same steps ?

Comment: you can use visual web part (farm) using VS and deploy it onto your server and it will show you under Custom section in the webparts.

Comment: i have these two questions; where i should add the "custom buttons Save" code , inside the OnInit method ? Second question i am unable to reference the "site" inside the PageLoad method and VS will show a red link under it, so do i need to define it somewhere ?

Comment: Please see the edited code. And you can add a asp:button control on visual web part and add the button click event with the code.

Comment: can you check my Edit to the original question please ?

Comment: sorry, use web instead site.

Comment: and where i should add the custom save button code? inside the oninit method as i am currently doing ?

Comment: also i am unable to reference "site.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup"

Comment: no you should use save button code,not on OnInit(), and use web.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup()-code edited.

Comment: i know this might be out of the original question,but could you explain where/how to add the save button code ?

Comment: check the edited answer

Comment: thanks again for your edit, but where i should add the Asp Control ? second question also what does txtTitle.Text represents exactly ? i meam from where i can get the real name for the txtTitle?

Comment: in your visual webpart you must have a .ascx file, here you can place your page controls. n txtTitle is just the sample control tht i have used here. you need to represent your controls instead.

Comment: can you check my second edit to the original question "Edit Two" as i think that i am missing where to place your code inside my web part ,,,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17370/discussion-between-hardik-kothari-and-john-g).

Comment: check the edited reference for ASCX file. include the asp control in that file

Comment: ok i got your point, but now i want to know exactly how i can know the "textbox" names for my fields? is this simply the user friendly name such as "Status" , "Title" , etc?

Comment: yes those are the id's for the controls you use on server side

Comment: but now what i should write instead of "textbox.Visible=false;" should i replace the textbox with the item name such as "Assingedto.Visisle"?

Comment: can you please show my the exact syntax?

Comment: yes your field id i.e: AssignedTo.Visible=false;

Comment: and what is txtTitle in "   txtTitle.Text = item["Title"] as string;"  ??

Comment: since this is the EditForm, the notation is used for fetching the value from list

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can achieve it.  It depends on how many users you will have accessing the list.  On several occasions, I create lists where only a single manager will be accessing the page.  Instead of creating separate views, you can control access based on the username.

You can encapsulate the manager only data fields in a section.
[image]

You will then create a text data field with the formula User().  This will return the username of the individual accessing the form.

[image]

After that simply create rule telling the section to hide if a certain username is not returned.  So if I wanted to only show this section to myself, I would set to hide the field if my username did not return.

[image]

As I stated, however, it completely depends on how many users this is being targeted for.

Comment: But can i specify the rule to hide the fields is the login user is not inside a certain sharepoint user group ? as currently we have 10 users defined as managers and they can see all fields. but those 10 users might be expanded or reduced ....

Comment: This method is only going to return a single user name.  It won't be able to tell what groups they belong to.  If you have a group that is constantly changing this might not be the best way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript/Jquery to hide control in editform page of list.
Whenever user edit an item, hide manager's related field.
User querystring and read it to make manager's related field visible. As you may be sending url to your manager in email, include querystring in that url so that only manager related field are visible while rest of fields were hidden.